# Sqlite3, Python, and Tkinter Login

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to Verify a user But i am having trouble. I know that there is this certain user in the database But when i try to type it python prints nothing please help. if any questions leave in the comments below.

```py
UsernameVar = StringVar()
PasswordVar = StringVar()
USERNAMELB = Label(root,text="Username:",font=('arial',20,'bold'))
PASSWORDLB = Label(root,text="Password:",font=('arial',20,'bold'))
USERNAME_ENTRY = Entry(root,font=('arial',20,'bold'),textvariable=UsernameVar)
PASSWORD_ENTRY = Entry(root,font=('arial',20,'bold'),show='*',textvariable=PasswordVar)
USERNAMELB.grid(column=0,row=0)
PASSWORDLB.grid(column=0,row=1)
USERNAME_ENTRY.grid(column=1,row=0)
PASSWORD_ENTRY.grid(column=1,row=1)

results = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Userinfo WHERE username=? AND password=?",( UsernameVar.get(), PasswordVar.get(),))
def Login():
    c.execute("""SELECT *
    FROM  Userinfo
    WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?)
    """,(UsernameVar.get(), PasswordVar.get(),))
    results = c.fetchall()
    x = UsernameVar.get()
    y = PasswordVar.get()
    for query_result in c.fetchall():
        if x in query_result:
            print('Username already exists') 
        else:
            print("Username doesn't exist" )
```

Comment: Why not just use `for query_result in results:` ? Instead you could search with the input they give and if it returns `[]` which means no query, then the user does not exist

Comment: So i think i know what you are talking about but not to sure. I fixed my code may you help me again USer errror is not being printed.

Comment: ```pythonc.execute("""SELECT *
    FROM  Userinfo
    WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?)
    """,(UsernameVar.get(), PasswordVar.get(),))
    results = c.fetchall()
    x = UsernameVar.get()
    y = PasswordVar.get()
    for query_result in results:
        if x in query_result:
            if y in query_result:
                print("USerName Exists") 
        if x not in query_result:
            print("USer errror")

Comment: Update the Q with this please, cant understand from the comments

Comment: But now it is printing USerName Exists
USer errror

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you have called `fetchall()` twice.  The later call should get nothing, that's why you got nothing in the console.

Basically you only have one record for each user in the `Userinfo` table, therefore you just need to check whether record is returned:

```py
def Login():
    c.execute("""SELECT * FROM  Userinfo WHERE username = ? AND password = ?""", (UsernameVar.get(), PasswordVar.get(),))
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result:
        print('Login successful') 
    else:
        print("Login failed" )
```

Please note that saving sensitive data, like password, in plain text is not recommended.  Sensitive data should be encrypted.

Comment: What happens when `fetchall()` is called twice?

Comment: @CoolCloud I have said in my answer *"The later call should get nothing"*.

Comment: I am still getting noting prited out even tho i know there is that password and usernmae

Comment: Oh wait nvm i solved it thx so much to all of you who helped me

Comment: @DanielZhelezonv You should get either "Login successful" or "Login failed" because it is simple if/else statements.